# CS0103 The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

This is my DBHelper Class

```
namespace Oficina.Dados
{
    public class DbHelper
    {
        public SqlCommand ExecutarProcedure(string procedure)
        {
            //Definir o comando
            var cmd = new SqlCommand();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = procedure;
                cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cnOficina);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                return cmd;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public SqlCommand ExecutarProcedure(string procedure, List<SqlParameter> parametros)
        {
            var cmd = ExecutarProcedure(procedure);
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());
                return cmd;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public class ClienteDados : DbHelper
        {

        }

    }
}
```

And, when I try to use the "Executar Procedure" in this class, I get the error CS0103

```
namespace Oficina.Dados
{
    public class ClienteDados
    {
        public List<ClienteModelo> ListarClientes()
        {
            try
            {
                //Definir o leitor
                SqlDataReader leitor = ExecutarProcedure("pCliente_SEL_Todos").ExecuteReader();

                //Definir uma lista do tipo ClienteModelo
                List<ClienteModelo> lista = new
                List<ClienteModelo>();

                //Adicionar um cliente em branco na lista
                lista.Add(new ClienteModelo()
                {
                    Codigo = 0,
                    Nome = "",
                    Email = "",
                    Nascimento = DateTime.Now
                });

                //Verificar se o leitor está lendo registros
                while (leitor.Read())
                {
                    //Adicionar os clientes à lista
                    lista.Add(new ClienteModelo()
                    {
                        Codigo = (int)leitor["Codigo"],
                        Nome = leitor["Nome"].ToString(),
                        Email = leitor["Email"].ToString(),
                        Nascimento = (DateTime)leitor["Nascimento"]
                    });
                }

                //Fechar o leitor
                leitor.Close();

                //Retornar a lista
                return lista;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The error message also mention the name that does not exist in the current context. Do you think it might help to understand what is the problem?

Comment: You haven't created an instance of `DbHelper`.

Comment: I guess it should, but I have no clue why, since the method is public and both classes are under the same projetc.

Comment: The point is that you should show the *complete* error message, and highlight which line it occurs at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined two `ClienteDados` classes, one of them is an inner class in `DbHelper` and inherits from it, and the other one stands alone and doesn't inherits from `DbHelper`. The methods are also not static so there is no reason for the second `ClienteDados` to know them.

Have it inherit from `DbHelper` and delete the inner `ClienteDados` in `DbHelper`.

```
namespace Oficina.Dados
{
    public class ClienteDados : DbHelper
    {
        //...
    }
}

namespace Oficina.Dados
{
    public class DbHelper
    {
        public SqlCommand ExecutarProcedure(string procedure) { //... }

        public SqlCommand ExecutarProcedure(string procedure, List<SqlParameter> parametros) { //... }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, now I get it, thanks Guy, appreciate the time and the help.